# PHP mail script newline and special characters

Tags: php

I'm using the following mail script but the problem is that it converts some characters.
A typical mail looks like this:

```
Neue Nachricht von Mustermann, Max (bla@blub.de):
Hallo Herr Platzhalter,&#13;&#10;wie soeben besprochen, würden wir gern ein
&#34;Schild&#34; mit der Aufschrift  &#34;Aufschrift&#34; bei Ihnen
bestellen.&#13;&#10;Bitte teilen Sie uns doch mit, wie wir da
verfahren müssen ... &#13;&#10;Ihnen einen schönen
Urlaub!&#13;&#10;Familie Mustermann
```

I'd guess that this ($message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);) messes it up. So how do I change that without making it unsecure? And are there other improvements I should add to that script?

```
<?php
    //Enter your email here
    $your_email = "mymail";
    //Enter the subject of the mail here
    $subject = "Kontakt Webseite";


    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    //Filter HTML characters
    $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    $error = "Fehler: ";

    //Default message if unsuccessful and no other reason found
    $return_message = $error."Leider hat das Versenden der Nachricht nicht geklappt, bitte schreiben Sie mir direkt an  ".$your_email." eine E-Mail";
    if(strlen($name) > 0 && strlen($email) > 0 && strlen($message) > 0) {
        if(filter_var(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)) {
            try {
                $body = "Neue Nachricht von ".$name." (".$email."):\n".$message;
                $header = "From: ".$email;
                mail($your_email, $subject, $body, $header);
                $return_message = "Die Nachricht wurde erfolgreich versendet, ich melde mich schnellst möglich bei Ihnen";
            }
            catch(Exception $e) { }
        } else {
            $return_message = $error."Ihre E-Mail Adresse scheint ungültig zu sein.";
        }
    } else {
        $return_message = $error."Ein oder mehrere Felder waren nicht ausgefüllt.";     
    }
    echo $return_message;
?>
```

Comment: Is it really neccessary to escape the string you will send by mail? PHP will handle any issues, it's not like you are using it for a MySQL Query

Comment: I don't know.. I've nearly no experiences with php.. That script was included in a bought template. I thought it was something security related and didn't want to mess something up without asking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing it would really be doing is trying to make sure the receiving client could handle it properly, and there's never any guarantee of that anyhow :P

In this case, it's turning your special characters into HTML entities (`\n` -> `&#10`, for example), which would break your emails without a fair amount of work to fix them up again. Get rid of the filter and you should be good.

Comment: thanks for your answer i'll remove that filter.. on this site (http://safalra.com/programming/php/contact-feedback-form/) they are using something like this: $crack=eregi("(\r|\n)(to:|from:|cc:|bcc:)",$body); should I add something like that or is it obsolete?

Answer (score 1):

Slokun makes a valid point. Additionally, as the emails content contains HTML entities and appears to be in another language, it would be a good idea to append the following to the email header to ensure correct rendering by receiving email clients:

Replace:

```
$header = "From: ".$email;
```

With:

```
$header = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
```

Edit: Having said that, if you include the above lines in your script you won't need to remove the line that sanitizes HTML entities. Your problem at the moment is that receiving email clients are not interpreting the emails content as HTML but pure text.

Comment: Ok, seems to be a good idea to send it as an html mail :) what do you think about my comment under Slokuns post?

Comment: @kannix I can't say i've ever seen that form of implementation, however i'm not accustomed to having built a vast number of mailing scripts. Typically i try not to re-invent the wheel and use a well established vetted script. A good example being phpMailer: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: @kannix By all means utilise the regex, but if you do ensure that you replace 'ereg' with 'preg_match' as it's been deprecated as of php 5.3